# How to fetch data from sqlite using python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using this sample [sqlite database](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/) and my code is

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chinook.db')
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks")
rows = conn.cursor().fetchall()
```

It should have worked, but `rows` is empty?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You never `.execute()` the cursor.

Comment: @Corion: `conn.execute()` is a shortcut. It does, however, return the cursor, which is where the problem is.

Comment: what is the right way to execute cursor(). is it `conn.cursor().fetchall();
conn.execute()`

Comment: @Eka: it's all in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`Connection.execute` shortcut](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) returns a `cursor` instance, which you need to use with `fetchall`. In your code, you're creating a new, independent cursor.

Thus:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chinook.db')
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

or even shorter (not recommended, but for those who like obscured one-liners):

```
rows = sqlite3.connect('chinook.db').execute("SELECT * FROM tracks").fetchall()
```

Or don't use `Connection.execute` shortcut, to avoid confusion:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chinook.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: It's true that the OP was using Python 2, but your code would work perfectly in both versions with the parenthesis added. This is currently one of the top results on Google for using SQLite with Python, so most people seeing your answer are using Python 3. Since OP has probably long since moved on, would you please reconsider making the answer apply to both versions?